# Restore recycler view state when navigating back to the fragment - using the jetpacks navigation architecture

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack

I am using the latest jetpacks navigation architecture. I have a fragment that contains a recycler view and this recycler view displays a list of items. When an item is clicked, it takes you to the item details fragment. So, when I navigate back from the details fragment, I want the page to retain the position of the item which the user clicked instead of scrolling all the way to the top of item list. Is there a way in the new jetpacks navigation architecture to "add" a fragment? Looks like fragments are always "replaced"? Is there a way to change this default behavior?

Comment: RecyclerView automatically restores its position if you've written your Fragment correctly, whether you use Navigation or not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late, but it might help someone

a hack-way is to store the view in local variable and restore it when fragment is loaded again (after back navigation) inside onCreateView

assuming you are using binding then

```
private var rootView: View? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.id, container, false)

        if(rootView == null) {
            rootView = binding.root
            return binding.root
        }

        return rootView


    }
```